# Get and decode a response from RestTemplate spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, utf-8, encode, urlencode, decoding

I am encoding a URL and when I get the response back it is encoded as well. What I am having a issue with is decoding it.

```
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(text,"UTF-8");

        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder
            .fromUriString("https://google.com/translate")
            .queryParam("srcLang", srcLang)
            .queryParam("tgtLang", tgtLang)
            .queryParam("text", encoded);

        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString(),HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
```

what I was trying to do is:

`String decodedResult = UriUtils.decode(response.toString(),"UTF-8");`

But that didn't work.

advice?

Answer (score 1):

response object is of ResponseEntity type. You should first get body from response then decode it.

```
String decodedResult = UriUtils.decode(response.getBody(),"UTF-8");
```